# User deleted/undeleted post which caused queue to invalidate

Tags: bug

What's the proper procedure for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781050/4875631)?

- Post was marked by me as NAA (It could be considered an answer by a
  mod, but it's rather low quality.)
- Went through the VLQ queue and got
  3 votes for deletion.
- User deleted/undeleted his post. No edits were made.
- Queue was invalidated

I feel like this should be deleted, but may not be a question specifically a moderator would find to their standards as NAA if I flag it for review. What would be the recommended path here? Is there a different path for >10k users?

Is this a bug? I feel like it should reopen the queue in progress if no edit was made.

Comment: "It could be considered an answer"  Then **don't flag it as NAA**.  Flagging answers as NAA is completely inappropriate.  If you don't think it's a *good* answer, then downvote it; don't lie and claim that the answer isn't an answer when you know full well that it's an answer.  Be thankful that the answerer prevented you from abusing moderation privileges to delete an answer that doesn't merit deletion.

Comment: This seems like a user trying to abuse the system. Either way I agree the answer should be deleted and the question flagged as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._ it that is actually the issue.

Comment: @George On what basis do you think that the answer to the question should be deleted?  Note that the question no longer being reproducible by its author isn't grounds for deleting an answer, not that there's any evidence that that's the case.

Comment: @Servy It's not due to the question being no longer reproducible, it's due to it being a typographical/ simple syntax error _I think there should be an syntax error and you should add `});`_ Which while yes, could be an answer to the question it shouldn't be, it should be a flag on the question itself, although I half agree with you about not flagging it as NAA, to me (at least) it's on the line of being NAA and being an attempt at an answer.

Comment: Regardless of the answer (which is an attempt to answer however craptastic it is, so it isn't NaA), the question is lacking an MCVE, a proper problem statement, steps to reproduce, etc, etc, etc. Ultimately craptastic questions are going to attract craptastic answers. I can't help but notice that in 19 hours, mine is the first close vote on that question.

Comment: I don't fully see what's supposed to happen in these cases... Since the question is logically closable (typo, non-repro), we do not want answers for it (since that's the point of closing questions, I think). But someone answered this bad question before it got closed, and since it's an honest attempt to answer the question... then that answer shouldn't be deleted. I see these things kinda working against each other. Not sure what **should** happen, but I feel the outcome we get with these rules is not the one we want.

Comment: @yivi close then delete the question, the answers are deleted when the question is deleted. Just because the answer shouldn't be flagged doesn't mean it shouldn't be deleted. 20K+ rep users could and should vote to delete such answers (if the question was half decent), but being that the question is problematic, it can be dealt with.

Comment: [Similar post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197964/350567)

Comment: @yivi: The beauty of the typo close reason is that questions closed with that reason don't need to stick around, so it doesn't matter whether the answer gets deleted first, since it's not going to survive the deletion of the *question*, which is the more important part. Though it's worth deleting an answer if it's been upvoted, to give the asker a chance to self-delete instead of making other users spend their delete votes.

Comment: @gnat Not even close to duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock. I see what you mean. As a lowly 2k without delete nor close votes, it simply seems that sometimes getting rid of trashy posts is a bit hard... although I'm aware that changing the balance is a delicate thing and that the system _mostly_ works.

Comment: duplicate explains why you are blocked. If your NAA flag was legitimate the answer to your question would be trivial, do a custom flag with message like this: "this is a question dumped into answer box (or: link-only answer, or edit to the question etc). Using custom flag because my prior NAA was shaken off by OP deletion/undeletion: <provide link to answer revisions history or timeline to make it easier for mod to see>". I cast flags like that almost daily and these work like a charm