# Helpful flag for link-only answer does not lead to answer deletion

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer, helpful-flags

I raised a not-an-answer (NAA) flag for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530832/capsule-network-and-reproducibly/58530950#58530950):

[image]

which was indeed accepted ("helpful"), but did not lead to deletion of the answer.

Shouldn't the helpful NAA flag here lead to deletion, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sometimes moderators don't delete answers that are so new to give the OP time to fix them; othertimes moderators see that they're helpful and don't want to delete helpful content; othertimes moderators hit the 'helpful' button and move on. One of those "You're right but I'm not going to do anything" situations. Othertimes they hit helpful and forget to handle the flag.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thanks, but stepping-in yourself and literally *transfiguring* the answer to something completely different I guess is not one of the possible reasons. Can't actually figure out why you bothered to do so instead of posting a new answer yourself though - do you think it will be a good example & lesson for the respondent?

Comment: @desertnaut I don't need the reputation myself; the OP came up with the link; all I did was take the bits from the link necessary to keep the answer around if the link died.  One of the tenets of Stack Overflow is to edit answers to improve them; I'm just exercising that muscle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was [deleted and undeleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58530950/timeline) by the answerer.  This [invalidated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360618/1364007) the [the Low Quality Posts review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24393136) (which had not had any actions on it yet) and your flag was marked helpful automatically.

I've noticed this happening for posts in the past where a user posts a non-answer answer, gets downvoted, then deletes and undeletes the answer hoping that will clear the downvotes.

Note that if it were deleted in review them undeleted by the answerer, a flag [is automatically raised by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/284827) for a diamond moderator to investigate.

In cases of irretrievable NAA posts (like "I have this problem too" posts), the post should be re-flagged so it can have a second chance at deletion.

Comment: Diamond moderators get notifications about posts that are deleted through review and then undeleted by the original poster, but that's the only case in which we are notified. A single flag isn't sufficient. Please re-flag these if you see them. Leaving a comment isn't especially useful, and just leads to arguments.

Comment: You mean re-flag with a custom moderator flag, since the NAA one would not be available cc @CodyGray

Comment: Sure. That's what custom flags are for. Be sure to explain *why* you're using a custom flag to ensure that a moderator in a hurry won't decline your flag on an invalid basis (the whole shoulda-used-a-standard-flag business).